# I/O bound & compute-bound processes . Greater throughput?

Tags: io, computer-science, multitasking

A process is said to be I/O-bound if it requires
a lot of I/O operations, whereas a process that
consists of mostly computations within the
CPU/memory system is said to be compute-bound

**Would greater throughput be achieved by a
system running two processes in a multi-programming enviroment if both processes were I/O bound or if one were I/O bound and the other were compute-bound? Why?**

***EDIT:** i think having an i/o bound and a compute-bound processes can achieve a greater throughput,and that's why the i/o bound runs in the background as long as the compute-bound process runs normaly with the help of the cpu. 
**What you think? I need some help over here**

Comment: Ah, googled it. Multiprogramming is multitasking on a uniprocessor system.

Comment: yeah i know that. But, about my question, what you think? @Potatoswatter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A process is said to be I/O bound if it occupies I/O resources while running. A process that occupies CPU resources is called compute-bound.

If you have one task of each kind, then you can keep the I/O channel busy with one task and the CPU busy with the other. Occasionally the CPU must acknowledge I/O operation completion and begin another I/O, and perhaps the compute-bound process needs the disk occasionally. But on the whole the tasks should not slow each other down.

Example of compute-bound task: scrolling through a list of files in the file browser. (Well, back in the day.) Example of I/O bound task: copying a file.

You would expect to be able to do both at the same time, with at most occasional stalls.

If both are I/O bound, that is like copying two files. Unless they are going over different I/O channels (for example back one file to disc and upload another file), you are not going to go faster than a simple task queue.

Comment: so,as long as i understand, having one task of each kind ( I/O & compute) achieves a greater throughput than having two I/O tasks. Am i right? @Potatoswatter

Comment: @Socratεs Having tasks in competition reduces throughput for those tasks. All I/O tasks do not in reality compete with each other, but you have the gist of the question.

Comment: knowing that no i/o tasks compete with each other,it is logical to me to have two i/o tasks running ,in order to achieve greater throughput,rather than having one i/o and one compute-bound @Potatoswatter

Comment: @Socratεs Yes, you would want to run as many concurrent, non-competing I/O tasks as possible. Example: downloading a file and saving it to disk. For that matter, you could do the compute-bound task at the same time as well.